# How can I draw truth tables using Mathematica

Tags: evaluation, boolean-computation, logic

For instance, the given expression `p ⊕ (p v q)`
In the problem I'm trying to solve. There's a Mathematica answer to this:

```
p → ¬ q
```

which is:

```
BooleanTable[{p, Implies[p, ! p]}, {p}]// TableForm

True   False
False  True
```

I would appreciate some guidance on how to approach this so I can do the rest on my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
BooleanTable[Xor[p, p || q], {p}, {q}] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: why did you use {p}, {q} instead of {p, q}?

Comment: @wa7d The only reason is that with `{p}, {q}` I get the data in a nested list that I can pass directly to `TableForm`. With `{p,q}` the values are not sorted into columns and rows.